# Minio s3:ListAllMyBucket bucket policy not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stack-overflow, minio

**My objective is userone buckets shoud not show to other users:**

**s3:ListAllMyBucket**
Returns a list of all buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request. To use this operation, you must have the s3:ListAllMyBuckets permission.

This is my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

***s3.ListAllMyBuckets is not working i don't know why?***
**If i misunderstand something please let me know**

This Solution works but i need to know why s3:ListAllMyBuckets not working or if misunderstand something please let me know

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::prefix*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "s3.ListAllMyBuckets is not working"? What did you do and what happened?

Comment: Users either have permission to list _ALL_ buckets, or _NO_ buckets. It is not possible to select _which_ buckets are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no concept of a 'bucket owner' in MinIO as there is in AWS S3. The `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` operation effectively grants access to the `ListBuckets` API operation.

For what you want, there are a few patterns you can explore:

- Using prefixes in a bucket per user and configuring the resource as `"arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}"`
- Creating a bucket per-user and creating a corresponding policy for that user only granting access to that bucket

MinIO adopts S3's deny-by-default attitude, so as long as you explicitly state which resources a user has access to, the others will fall off on their own.